# Unable to set correct background color to UISearchTextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uicolor

Please take a look at this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchController                                      = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.navigationItem.searchController                       = self.searchController;
    self.definesPresentationContext                            = YES;
    self.searchController.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Search", @"search placeholder");
    self.searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Looks pretty simple. I'm trying to set red background color to `UISearchTextField`. But unfortunately the result color is not precisely red. When I check the color with ColorSync utility it shows RGB as 0.9255, 0.0, 0.0667 which is not what I need. Of course red is just a simplified example. It applies to any color. Actually I need to set a color with precise RGB and unable to do so. Obviously iOS applies some tint to the search bar somehow. What I tried was: applying clear color as tint to the search bar and text field along with setting background image but all in vain. This little tint never goes away. Any ideas, guys? How do I set a precise color?

Comment: Have you tried view debugging to check wether there's some kind of overlay view?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution it will help you

```
import UIKit

extension UISearchBar {
    func getTf() -> UITextField? { return value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField }
    func setTf(color: UIColor) {
        guard let tf = getTf() else { return }
        switch searchBarStyle {
        case .minimal:
            tf.layer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
            tf.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        case .prominent: 
              break, 
        default: 
            tf.backgroundColor = color
        @unknown 
            default: break
        }
    }
}
```

**For Usage**

`searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal`